# XNA 4.0 draw a cube with DrawUserIndexedPrimitives method

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

EDIT

Since I read what Mark H suggested (thanks a lot, I found it very useful) I think my question can become clearer structured this way:

Using XNA 4.0, I'm trying to draw a cube.

Im using this  method:

```
GraphicsDevice.DrawUserIndexedPrimitives<VertexPositionColor>(
    PrimitiveType.LineList,
    primitiveList,
    0,  // vertex buffer offset to add to each element of the index buffer
    8,  // number of vertices in pointList
    lineListIndices,  // the index buffer
    0,  // first index element to read
    7   // number of primitives to draw
);
```

I got the code sample from [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb196414.aspx) which simply draw a serie of triangles.
I want to modify this code in order to draw a cube. I was able to slitghly move the camera so I can have the perception of solidity, I set the vertex array to contain the 8 points defining a cube. But I can't fully understand how many primitives I have to draw (last parameter) for each of `PrimitiveType`.

So, I wasn't able to draw the cube (just some of the edges in a non-defined order).

More in detail:

to build the vertex index list, the sample used

```
// Initialize an array of indices of type short.
lineListIndices = new short[(points * 2) - 2];

// Populate the array with references to indices in the vertex buffer
for (int i = 0; i < points - 1; i++)
{
    lineListIndices[i * 2] = (short)(i);
    lineListIndices[(i * 2) + 1] = (short)(i + 1);
}
```

I'm ashamed to say I cannot do the same in the case of a cube.

- what has to be the size of the `lineListIndices`?
- how should I populate it? In which order?

And how do these things change when I use a different `PrimitiveType`?

In the code sample there are also another couple of calls which I cannot fully understand, which are:

```
// Initialize the vertex buffer, allocating memory for each vertex.
vertexBuffer = new VertexBuffer(graphics.GraphicsDevice, vertexDeclaration,
points, BufferUsage.None);

// Set the vertex buffer data to the array of vertices.
vertexBuffer.SetData<VertexPositionColor>(pointList);
```

and

```
vertexDeclaration = new VertexDeclaration(new VertexElement[]
  {
    new VertexElement(0, VertexElementFormat.Vector3, VertexElementUsage.Position, 0),
    new VertexElement(12, VertexElementFormat.Color, VertexElementUsage.Color, 0)
  }
);
```

that is, for `VertexBuffer` and `VertexDeclaration` I could not find and significant (monkey-like) guide. I reported them too because I think they could be involded in understanding things.

I think I also have to understand something related to the order the vertexes are stored in the array. But actually I have no clue of what I should learn to have this function drawing a cube. So, if anybody could point me to the right direction, it wil be appreciated.

Hope to have made myself clear this time

Comment: To better ask here, check this small guides [ask] and http://sscce.org

Comment: An explanation with diagrams can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205124%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually I was able to find a worthful [guide](http://www.i-programmer.info/projects/119-graphics-and-games/1108-getting-started-with-3d-xna.html?start=1) to draw a cube. In there they use `DrawUserPrimitive<T>` method but the difference is quite a thin one. I had no difficulties in using both methods. As you will see, this guide includes explainations on every concern of drawing a cube, like the order vertexes have to be stored and then drawn, and number of primitives to pass the drawing method.
Hope this could be of help to anyone who will be struggling with this problem  such as I was.